# Best Practices for Apache Http Client 4.5.11 Configuration in Production

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Below is My `ApacheHttpClient` Spring bean and am wondering whether the configuration I have suits for Production or do I need to tweak any configurations? Can someone please share some info, if you are using latest Apache Http Client in production

```
@Service
public class ApacheHttpClient implements IHttpClient {
    private static final Logger              LOGGER                                             = Logger
            .getInstance(ApacheHttpClient.class);
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS                      = 400;
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_IDLE_CONNECTION_EVICTION_FREQUENCY_SECONDS = 300;
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE                  = DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS;

    private static final int                 DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS            = (60 * 1000);
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS                  = (4 * 60 * 1000);
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS                  = (60 * 1000);
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_VALIDATE_AFTER_INACTIVITY_MILLISECONDS     = (5 * 60 * 1000);

    private static final int                 DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE_MILLISECONDS                    = (5 * 60 * 1000);
    private static final int                 DEFAULT_REQUEST_RETRY                              = 2;

    @Autowired
    private SSLContextHelper                 customSSLContext;

    private int                              keepAlive                                          = DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE_MILLISECONDS;
    private int                              maxTotalConnections                                = DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS;

    private int                              maxConnectionsPerRoute                             = DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE;
    private int                              connectTimeout                                     = DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;
    private int                              readTimeout                                        = DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;

    private int                              waitTimeout                                        = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;
    private int                              requestRetry                                       = DEFAULT_REQUEST_RETRY;

    private CloseableHttpClient              httpClient;

    private ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy      keepAliveStrategy                                  = (response,
            context) -> {
                                                                                                    HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
                                                                                                            response.headerIterator(
                                                                                                                    HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
                                                                                                    while (it
                                                                                                            .hasNext()) {
                                                                                                        HeaderElement he = it
                                                                                                                .nextElement();
                                                                                                        String param = he
                                                                                                                .getName();
                                                                                                        String value = he
                                                                                                                .getValue();
                                                                                                        if (value != null
                                                                                                                && param.equalsIgnoreCase(
                                                                                                                        "timeout")) {
                                                                                                            try {
                                                                                                                return Long
                                                                                                                        .parseLong(
                                                                                                                                value)
                                                                                                                        * 1000;
                                                                                                            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {}
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                    return keepAlive;
                                                                                                };


    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeApacheHttpClient() {

        // config timeout
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(waitTimeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(readTimeout).build();
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(customSSLContext.getSSLContext())).build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);

        connManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConnections);

        // Increase default max connection per route
        connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute);

        // Defines period of inactivity in milliseconds after which persistent connections must be re-validated prior to
        // being reused
        connManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(DEFAULT_VALIDATE_AFTER_INACTIVITY_MILLISECONDS);

        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy).setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .setConnectionManagerShared(true).setSSLContext(customSSLContext.getSSLContext())
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(requestRetry, true))
                .build();

        // detect idle and expired connections and close them
        IdleConnectionEvictor staleMonitor = new IdleConnectionEvictor(connManager, DEFAULT_IDLE_CONNECTION_EVICTION_FREQUENCY_SECONDS);
        staleMonitor.start();

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Initialize ApacheHttpClient is successful");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if a clear objective answer can be given to this question. There is no single set of settings that will work for all applications. Your production environment and application will be unique.

Some items to evaluate are:

- Set timeouts consistent with the response times that your users or upstream callers will tolerate
- Set connection limits consistent with the number of connections needed to support your expected maximum traffic
- Set retries appropriate for your application - Will your application tolerate a retry or would that induce a problematic behavior because it replays a request?

You also need to look at monitoring and observe your logs and realtime metrics for connections, memory usage, response times, timeouts, errors, etc.

The defaults from Apache are likely good defaults. The Apache Foundation and the engineers that assist it are experienced and put thought into those defaults.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the (non-official) Apache HttpClient 5.0 migration guide regarding recommended configuration parameters and good practices for **Apache HttpClient 4.5.x versions**.

https://ok2c.github.io/httpclient-migration-guide/preparation.html

Two most important recommendations:

- Always re-use CloseableHttpClient instances. They are expensive to create, but they are also fully thread safe, so multiple threads can use the same instance of CloseableHttpClient to execute multiple requests concurrently taking full advantage of persistent connection re-use and connection pooling.
- Consume response content directly from the content stream and convert it to a higher level object without converting it to an intermediate string or byte array.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that having `requestRetry` value greater than `0` causing `SocketException` in our production environment so we have set the `requestRetry = 0` and we were not getting any `SocketException` exceptions